# django router with more than one numeric parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django DefaultRouter and can make api call such as :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/groups/3/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/groups/3/ranking
```

But i can only have one numeric parameter pk = 3, how can i make it accept **two numeric parameters** like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/groups/1/inviteUser/2/
```

My code is
urls.py

```
router_v1 = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)
router_v1.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet, 'h')
```

views.py

```
class GroupViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
....
    @action()
    def inviteUser(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

the only ugly way i found is

```
 url(r'^api/v1/groups/(?P<pk>\d+)/inviteUser/(?P<pk2>\d+)/', something)
```

Comment: You should at least have explained that you are using Django REST framework. The code you've shown isn't part of default Django.

Comment: yes sorry, but i tagged it as django-rest-framework

Comment: Er no, I added that tag.

Comment: The way you've 'found' isn't ugly, it's the correct way to do it. The only change I would make would be to give the numeric parameters more descriptive names.

Comment: drf nested routes can do the job for you: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers